# How to map value from one observable to pair with depending observable value?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

Suppose I have two observables:

`Observable<MainInfo> mainInfoObs` and

`Observable<AdditionalInfo> additionalInfoObs(MainInfo mainInfo)` function.

I want somehow to combine these observables to receive `Pair<MainInfo, AdditionalInfo>`

I can't just use zip, because `additionalInfoObs` depends on `mainInfo`.

So I want to do something like

```
mainInfoObs
    .map(mainInfo->new Pair(mainInfo,
                    getAdditionalInfo(mainInfo).toBlocking().last()
                    )
        )
```

But that blocks and hangs.

Please help me - how to combine observables as I want?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that flatMap has a variant with 2 arguments, which is what I need.
Here is my solution with flatmap:

```
mainInfoObs.flatMap(mainInfo->getAdditionalInfo(mainInfo), Pair::new)
```